# How to create a simple CLion C++ CMake project with different locations for Project itself, build products and source files

Tags: c++, cmake, clion

I'm new with CLion and CMakeList. I'd like to have different locations for:

1. CLion project files
2. Build Files
3. Source and Header Files

When opening default projects all are located under the same directory tree

What are the steps to create such project ('Hello world')?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. CLion project files

AFAIK, you can only set one global path for each jetbrains' IDE, by writing `IDE_HOME\bin\idea.properties` file.

Details can be found [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/articles/207240985-Changing-IDE-default-directories-used-for-config-plugins-and-caches-storage).

2. Build Files

`Settings` -> `Build, Execution, Deployment` -> `CMake` -> `Generation path`

You can also set several paths for different build profiles there.

[image]

3. Source and Header Files

Add sources and include directories in `CMakeLists.txt` .

Comment: There is no need to set `CMAKE_BUILD_TYPE` explicitly in CMake options. The build type is configured using the dropdown menu one line above.

Comment: I couldn't find a way to change ".idea" folder location, which include xml files of CLion (not configuration files as at first answer), so a workaround to prevent git "noise" with it, is to locate .gitignore file at this folder with single text line: !/.gitignore

Comment: @user10556443 I don't see, how this helps to prevent the .idea folder from being added to the repo. The proper way would be to place the `.gitignore` file in the root of the repository containing a line like `.idea/`. This way, the ignore is applied to every clone of the repository.